# Visual Studio test explorer runs tests in foreign language

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, test-explorer

I have created C# unit tests (using VS test tools). Among others, there are tests checking exceptions like that:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", e.Message);
```

When I open my unit test file and click "Run tests" in the context menu, everything works fine. When I use the test explorer of Visual Studio and click "Run tests" there, I get exceptions saying that the message of the exception is different. Actually, it is the same as the one I am checking for but in another language. The tests running in both cases are the same, there are no language changes or anything else, just simple logic tests. My OS is in English, Visual Studio as well. I have similar tests in another solution and there everything works fine. This solution and one of the projects that I am writing unit tests for were created by a colleague which has the system in this foreign language. However, I can't find settings like that anywhere. Does someone have an idea where these could be? How do I get the tests running always in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for the tests, in case someone else need it. It is not really good when the tests are language dependent, so I now check for the exception type:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(e, typeof(ArgumentNullException));
```

However, I would still like to know where the language is taken from. When I have everything in English, I really expect it to be in English.

Answer (score 1):

Try using HResult instead.

```
Assert.AreEqual(val, e.HResult)
```

Shouldn't change depending on language.
HResult is a coded numerical value assigned to a specific exception, so using HResult you know which exception is being thrown.

Edit:

Or if you know what exception you are expecting, you could write your own Exception-"expecter".

```
protected static void ThrowsException<T>(Action action) where T : Exception
    {
        var thrown = false;
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (T)
        {
            thrown = true;
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(thrown);
    }
```

And then use it like this:

```
ThrowsException<IndexOutOfRangeException>(() => MyController.MyAction());
```

Comment: I really don't want to use some strange integers, I simply wanted to know how to control the language of the tests and how is it possible to have a foreign language when my entire system is in English. But you are right, for the tests I should use something language-neutral, good point.

Comment: If you want it to be language independent you could use the strange integers, but bind them an enum. Then you see what exception it is in text.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use Throws with specific exception? Checking for a string message is really bad. In my opinion it's even cleaner than using IsInstanceOfType

```
var testDelegate = () => MyService.Method(params);
Assert.Throws<NullException>(testDelegate);
```